# add_image_size() to crop images into squares?

Tags: images, uploads, cropping

So I know about setting custom images with `add_image_size('name',X,Y,Crop?)` which is cool but  I need to build something that will crop images, regardless of their size, into squares.

Basically, I want to make sure the user's uploaded images will always be squares.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass `true` for the last `$crop` argument then so called "hard" crop mode is used. This will make WP produce results at exact size specified, except few edge cases (if image uploaded is smaller than specified size for example).

Note that *original* image is still retained as is. If you need to actually modify originals as well — that is out of what WP native sizes functionality is intended for, will have to do that with custom code.

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot of theme development is getting away from using add_image_size because WordPress makes way to many images. So rather than doing it that way, you can use a plugin or even a plugin that will integrate into your theme. Here is a good one that is easy to use

https://github.com/sy4mil/Aqua-Resizer

I think this is a better way to go than doing the add_image_size. from the script, you just call whatever size and shape you will need.

For example. Lets say you need an image that is 125 x 125 which would give you a nice square. You could do something like this inside the loop.

```
 $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
 $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use    "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
 $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 125, 125, true ); //resize & crop the image

 ?>

 <article <?php post_class()?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

<?php if($image) : ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image ?>"/>
<?php endif; ?>
```

That would take the featured image of the post and crop the image into a 125 x 125 sqaure and echo out the image.

You can see more [examples on this page](https://github.com/syamilmj/Aqua-Resizer/wiki/Examples)

Comment: I dont think that's going to work dor me. We are building a child theme for genesis so we have to use their hooks. Also, if I'm reading this right, that plugin requires that each image get manipulated manually.

Comment: That plugin can be easily integrated into your theme. You upload the folder and use and include in the function.php file. It doesn't have to be a plugin.

Comment: It still doesnt help me tho, it looks like I would have to manually adjust each image. And even if it didnt, what Im trying to do to crop all uploaded images into squares regardless of their size. This script looks like it adjusts each image manually, and with a set height and width.

Comment: well then maybe I don't understand what you are talking about. When you put in this plugin, you would replace the featured image with a call to the aq_resize function instead. So every image uploaded by the uploader would automatically be resized to whatever size you tell it. Like so aq_resize(510, 256); You would have to do the same thing with the featured image because you would have to call every image size that you created with add_image_size. Maybe you should add more information in your question so it makes more sense. This script resizes each image on the fly.

Comment: Answers should be [more than plain links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). They should actually be an answer instead of a route where someone will _maybe find_ an answer. Please help preventing link rot, [edit] your answer and provide the needed information that helps the OP as well as later visitors to solve their problem.